# Dictionary lookup causing objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed error

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a python dict/hashmap:

```
yearMapping = {"2016":"6", "2017":"7", "2018":"8", "2019":"9"}
```

I am trying to replace values within a DataFrame object with the corresponding map value. I wrote out an example below with my expected output.

I have 3 columns with data in them. If generated code is null, I am going to populate that column with the Contract Time + the map value.

```
Generated Code      |      Contract Date      |     Contract Time
    null            |         201607          |          1:31:01
```

Expected output:

```
Generated Code      |      Contract Date      |     Contract Time
    1:31:016        |         201607          |          1:31:01
```

What I am doing so far:

```
yearCode = df['Contract Date'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: x[:4])

df.loc[df["Generated Code"].isnull(),'Generated Code'] = df['Contract Time'] + yearMapping.get(yearCode)
```

I keep getting the error: **TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed**

Is this even do-able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) from `null` to `NaN`, then [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str) and last `Series` `yearCode` [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `dict`:

```
df['Generated Code'] = df['Generated Code'].replace({'null':np.nan})

yearMapping = {"2016":"6", "2017":"7", "2018":"8", "2019":"9"}

yearCode = df['Contract Date'].astype(str).str[:4]

df.loc[df["Generated Code"].isnull(),'Generated Code'] = 
df['Contract Time'] + yearCode.map(yearMapping)
print (df)
  Generated Code  Contract Date Contract Time
0       1:31:016         201607       1:31:01
```

Another solution is change condition:

```
yearMapping = {"2016":"6", "2017":"7", "2018":"8", "2019":"9"}
yearCode = df['Contract Date'].astype(str).str[:4]
df.loc[df["Generated Code"] == 'null','Generated Code'] = 
df['Contract Time'] + yearCode.map(yearMapping)
print (df)
  Generated Code  Contract Date Contract Time
0       1:31:016         201607       1:31:01
```